# Adding files from other directories to zip root directory with ZipFile

Tags: python, zip, python-zipfile

This seems like a fairly trivial question but I wasn't able to figure it out when I last worked on this project months ago, and I'm still not able to figure it out.

I have the following code

```
z = zipfile.ZipFile(make_file_safe(chapter_name) + '.cbz', 'a')
    for file in os.listdir('tmp'):
        z.write('tmp/' + file)
        os.remove('tmp/' + file)
```

What I am trying to do is take all the files in the `tmp` directory and add them to the root zip directory (so it would look something like `File.zip/1.jpg`, but no matter what I do it always end up as `File.zip/tmp/1.jpg`. If I try to change any of the directories in `z.write`, it isn't able to find the file anymore.

Comment: Set an explicit archive name for the file: `z.write('tmp/' + file, arcname=file)`.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thank you, that worked! I think when I had tried this before I thought that arcname was the name of the archive, not the name that would be given to the file in the archive.